# jQuery AJAX call returning images in wrong order - data synchronization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, asynchronous

I use a JQuery AJAX call to return image, name, address, country and score of a tourist attraction in a given city (by latitude). I save the returned data into 5 arrays: for images, names, addresses, country, and score.
Function "tom1" gets all data except images, it triggers function "tom2" that get image name.
Function "tom2" triggers function "callme".

When function call me appends all 5 values to the page, images often don't match the other info.

Is it related to the AJAX's asynchronous request?

Can you help me solve it? Here is my code:

```js
function tom1(lat, lon) {
  var queryURL = "https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/search/museum.json?key=" + tomAPI + "&lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon;

  $.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
  }).then(function(response) {

    //only select POIs which possess "dataSources" key = images
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      if (response.results[i].dataSources !== undefined) {
        poiId.push(response.results[i].dataSources.poiDetails[0].id);
        placeName.push(response.results[i].poi.name);
        address.push(response.results[i].address.freeformAddress);
        country.push(response.results[i].address.country);
        rank.push(response.results[i].score.toFixed(1));
      } else {
        console.log("not lucky today")
      }
    }
    tom2(poiId);
  });
}

// get POI details and images after you know POI's ID
function tom2(poiId) {

  for (i = 0; i < poiId.length; i++) {
    var queryURL = "https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/poiDetails.json?key=" + tomAPI + "&id=" + poiId[i];

    $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: "GET"
    }).then(function(response) {
      imgId.push(response.result.photos[0].id);
      callme(imgId);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you realize Ajax calls are Asynchronous? Hence the "A" in Ajax?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, tom2 makes a number of asynchronous calls, and the callback function of those can typically be executed in a different order. So the order of the elements in imgId will be mixed up.